# Get count(null) as zero in Grafana - InfluxDB data source

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Is it possible to set the value of count to zero when the result to which count is applied is null.

```
SELECT count(status) FROM ( SELECT last("P-status") AS "status" FROM "autogen"."Pl" WHERE ("Platform" = 'Database-plat' AND "P-status" = 'ERROR') AND time >= now() - 1m GROUP BY time(500ms), "Node" fill(0) )
```

In this case if the inner query returns null (for all the Node), count doesnt give any value , since fill will be ignored. I need the value to be zero, so that if i have to perform any other operation on the returned result, it can be done.

If possible, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but as it still is very relevant and I have been struggling with this problem for over a year now, I'd like to answer to this unanswered question with the current status of this issue according to my research:

The Github issues [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6400) and [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6412) imply that this problem is known since 2016 and not really understood by the contributers as a problem, as there are questionable rationales for the implementation (like "it's not a bug, it's a feature, because ambiguities of multiple series") that can easily be answered with special rules for unique series identification, but there has not been much activity any more despite heavy interest of the user community. Another point is that they have published version 2.x, which relies more on their new querying language (Flux), so it is very likely they have more or less practically abandoned the 1.x branch with InfluxQL (maybe except for QL backwards compatibility in 2.x and some minor updates, not sure).

Meanwhile I updated Grafana several times, but I had to stick with InfluxDB 1.x for a couple of reasons and the Flux support changed at some point (deprecated Flux plugin, but Flux included in standard InfluxDB plugin, but latter doesn't really work), so that Flux in Grafana is basically not working any more for a while now. I hoped for a better handling of the counting problem there, but now I'm out of luck regarding counting anything in InfluxDB reliably. I even tried some tricks with `sum()` function, fancy grouping and dummy values that I need to resubtract again and whatnot, but it always boiled down to the same conclusion: **InfluxDB can do a lot, but counting just doesn't work.**

It's very unsatisfying, but there doesn't seem to be a way to achieve the "eager" goal of counting data points without a system of bloated queries, excessive use of strange rules, dummy values and an insecurity that any query might break any time or break if you need to query only a specific time frame (where any dummy value workaround might not work). And regarding the priority given, this might not be fixed in the near future.